# Can you use a variable but also redeclare it locally in a closure?

Tags: javascript, html, scope, closures

A simple example of this is with lets, but it doesn't work with lets.

```js
let test = 1

{
  console.log(test) // Error cannot access 'test' before initialization
  let test = 2
}
console.log(test)
```

with var's it kind of works but using `var test = 2` or `test = 2` makes no difference so that's kind of weird to me because redeclaring test with `var test` should have a different behaviour than `test = 2` but it doesn't? :o

```js
var test = 1

{
  console.log(test) // 1
  var test = 2
  console.log(test) // 2
}

console.log(test) // 2
```

but what I want is

```
var test = 1

{
  console.log(test) // 1
  var test = 2
  console.log(test) // 2
}

console.log(test) // 1
```

Is there any way to achieve this????

I've been trying this but to no success:

```js
let test = 1

{
 let test = (new Function('return test'))()
 console.log(test) // 1
 test = 2
 console.log(test) // 2
 {
  let test = (new Function('return test'))()
  console.log(test) // 2
  test = 3
  console.log(test) // 3
 }
}

console.log(test) // 1
```

Comment: There's no *good* way. Impossible with `var`, since there will only be one binding, and reassigning it inside will be reflected on the outside. Possible but silly to do with `let`, by using the method in the linked answer to retrieve the value outside. Instead, use a different variable name.

Comment: @CertainPerformance if you have a *bad way* I'd love to hear it, I'm happy to use eval or whatever.

It's for an automated babel plugin for inheriting scope and accessing the parent scope of the current scope so the only way to do it is by using the same variable name :/

Comment: @lopu babel has ways to create collision-free identifiers and to rename variables in a  certain scope. Do that, not a runtime workaround that doesn't even work properly.

Comment: Declare the variables with `let`, then access the outer variable with `new Function('return test')()`. Only works if the outer variable is on the top level. Otherwise, it's completely impossible (unless you do something like manually reassign the value yourself at the end of the block). But please don't do this

Comment: @CertainPerformance oh it has been answered!! Hahaha oh that's hacky but ...

Comment: @CertainPerformance so wait is there no way to do it for more deeply nested scopes than just top-level -> 1st level? See my edit

Comment: No, unless the outer variable is on the top level, it's impossible

Comment: damnnnnn, what do you mean by manually reassign the value yourself at the end of the block..?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think it's kinda possible by double scoping? `{ let a = 1 ; { console.log(a) ; { let a = 2 } ; } ; console.log(a) // 1`

Comment: I guess, sure. If you don't need to access different variable bindings in the same block, that'll work

Comment: @CertainPerformance well *never say never* in JS :)

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible if you use the `with` statement to inject a mutable object as scope. Then you can mutate that to change the variables in scope dynamically:

```js
     let a = 1, context = {};

     with(context) {
       console.log(a);
       context.a = 2;
       console.log(a);
     }

     console.log(a);
```

But *please don't use this in any productive codebase*.

Comment: check my answer too you can literally just add a literal block `{}` to kinda hack it

Answer (score -1):

if you are ok with wrapping your code in a literal block then you can achieve it, but any code that needs access to the outer has to be in the parent block but this solution worked well enough in my case

```js
var foo = 'outer';

{
  var foo = 'inner';
  // rest of your code
}

console.log(foo);   // "outer"
```

Comment: you realize that `var` has function scoping, also it prints "inner" not "outer" (as expected)

Comment: @JonasWilms ah ok well it works with const and let :/